# Display first 4 of an array then next four on next

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to figure out a way to show only the first four elements in an array dynamically like some how filter it. There are 8 items. Is there a way to filter on the first 4. then when they click next, it displays the next four?

```js
$("#test").click(function(){
    fruits.splice(0, fruits.length, "Lemon", "Kiwi");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
    });
    $("#next").click(function(){
    fruits.next++;
});

function next(number)
{
    var index = fruits.indexOf(number);
    index++;
    if(index >= fruits.length)
        index = 0;
    return fruits[index];
}

var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "peaches", "bananas","papaya","watermelon","strawberry","cheese"];

var col1 = ["Banana", "Orange","pies","pretzels"];
var col2 = ["Banana", "Orange"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to add and remove elements.</p>
<button id="next" onclick="next();">next</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Time to learn about array methods like `filter()` or how to make array copy and then `slice()`. **[Start here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)** and toggle through methods in left menu

Comment: Where is `projects` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to selecting elements from array.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "peaches", "bananas","papaya","watermelon","strawberry","cheese"];

$("p").text(fruits.slice(0, 4));
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").text(fruits.slice(4, 8));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<button>Next</button>
```

Comment: is there a way I can just use index++ instead of hardcoding it to (4,8)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to rotate over items and after finish then returns to beginning this snippet would be the answer. Otherwise you can remove showed part of array to stop it from became visible again.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "peaches", "bananas", "papaya", "watermelon", "strawberry", "cheese", "melon"];
var items = $('#items');
var amount = 4;

function showNext() {
  var itemsToShow = fruits.slice(0, amount);
  items.text(itemsToShow);
  fruits = [...fruits.slice(amount), ...itemsToShow];
  // If wanna stop at the end just set fruit = fruits.slice(amount)
}

showNext();
$("#next").click(showNext);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="items"></p>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```